# How to join table multiple times in one query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have these two tables:

```
Master
---------
ID1 | ID2
---------
1 | 2
```

and

```
Detail
----------
ID | Name
----------
1 | name_of_id_1
2 | name_of_id_2
```

I want SQLQuery from Master where i get this:

```
name_of_id_1 | name_of_id_2
```

I have tried something like this but its not working

```
SELECT D1.Name, D2.Name FROM Master
INNER JOIN Detail AS D1
  ON D1.ID = Master.ID1
INNER JOIN Detail AS D2
  ON D2.ID = Master.ID2
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: You're already able to get what [you want](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=343f86269a4af772e01dc8858df808be)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thank you but your previous answer with "LEFT JOIN" actually solved my problem and its simplier

Comment: can you share what error did you get previously?

Comment: I didn't get any errors but the query just didn't return any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT d1.Name AS Name1, d2.Name AS Name2
  FROM Master m
  LEFT JOIN Detail d1
    ON d1.ID = m.ID1
  LEFT JOIN Detail d2
    ON d2.ID = m.ID2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1466c175e4db1a6bcf3b54c0100868bf)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To handle any number of possible names to join, you can use `group_concat`:

```
select group_concat(t2.name, " | ") from Master t1 join Details t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id or t1.id2 = t2.id k group by t1.id1
```